# Ошибка в "pgadmin 4" - The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите, почему при запуске pgadmin, я получаю The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted
Вот лог:

```
    pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_10864_LZJUFCQBRSZDOORX
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Произошел сбой NW.js. Перезапустить?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: DESKTOP-FHAPUMK
  - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  - DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  - GRADLE_HOME: C:\gradle-7.1.1
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\Kirill
  - JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\DESKTOP-FHAPUMK
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 2
  - OneDrive: C:\Users\Kirill\OneDrive
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin;C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin;C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 7b20dbdc-a333-4b41-af31-22b3767e2d08
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 63928
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 5e03
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
  - TEMP: C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\Kirill\AppData\Local\Temp
  - ULTRAMON_LANGDIR: C:\Program Files\UltraMon\Resources\ru
  - USERDOMAIN: DESKTOP-FHAPUMK
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: DESKTOP-FHAPUMK
  - USERNAME: Kirill
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\Kirill
  - windir: C:\Windows
--------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 39, in <module>
    import config
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from socketio import socketio_manage  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\socketio\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .zmq_manager import ZmqManager
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\socketio\zmq_manager.py", line 5, in <module>
    import eventlet.green.zmq as zmq
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\green\socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 71, in <module>
    setattr(dns.rdtypes.IN, pkg, import_patched('dns.rdtypes.IN.' + pkg))
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 61, in import_patched
    return patcher.import_patched(module_name, **modules)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\patcher.py", line 132, in import_patched
    return inject(
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\patcher.py", line 109, in inject
    module = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\dns\rdtypes\IN\WKS.py", line 25, in <module>
    _proto_tcp = socket.getprotobyname('tcp')
OSError: protocol not found
```

Comment: У Вас служба типа такой postgresql-x64-13 - запущена?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте установить: **pgAdmin 4 v5**. Удалите из папки: **C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming** файл **pgAdmin**. После установки **pgAdmin 4 v5**, запустите его от имени администратора.